# CSS3 transition (transform) not working in Firefox, but in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, prefixfree

I'm working on a simple slider, which uses CSS transitions to animate the slides. I created a pen with some basic styling and some javascript [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cbujK). Note: Since Codepen uses [Prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) I haven't used any prefixes.

The only part, which is animating is `.slider__anim`, not the `.slider__item` itself. I used `position: absolute` for all non active slides and `position: relative` for the active slide. That way I don't have to use a fixed height for my `.slider`.

In Chrome and Safari it works pretty well, but for some reason it just doesn't fire the CSS transitions in Firefox. Is this a bug in Firefox or is there any special markup for Firefox?

---

Comment: Did you used `-moz-transition`?

Comment: @KeesSonnema I'm using [autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) in my project and Codepen uses [Prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) to take care of all the different prefixes.

Comment: Allright, don't know how prefixfree works. :)

Comment: @demrks Seems to me that prefixfree breaks transforms on FF. updated the pen particularly for FF. Check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gudnq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everybody, who has the same problem: It's a bug in Firefox, see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289